# VBA go to next row and pull formula from above after data has been entered

Tags: vba, excel

I have the excel formula below to pull data from another sheet.

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yes",Sheet7!C4)),Sheet7!A4,"")

These cells used, C4 and A4, will always remain the same. Different item numbers are being scanned in one after another so the values in the cells will change.

When the word Yes is shown in C4 i would like it to record the item # in A4 into the new sheet. This formula works great for that.

However, after the item # is recorded in the new sheet, i would like it to go down to the next row and copy the formula so it can record the next item # scanned.

Is this VBA possible? thank you!

Comment: the item #'s scanned into excel will change. once the next item number is scanned, i want it to pull into the new sheet. Then another item # will be scanned into excel and i would like that number to be added to the next row in the sheet. in the end forming a list of item #'s that resulted in the "yes" value

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get something like

```
If Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C4").Value Like "*Yes*" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A4").Value
Else
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
End If
```

but don't use `ActiveCell` - use a proper reference to the cell in which you want to put the value.  (Your question doesn't contain enough information to determine what the location is, which is why I was forced to just refer to it as `ActiveCell`.)

---

Based on comments, it sounds like you want the following `Worksheet_Change` event in `Worksheets("Sheet7")`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Intersect(Range("A4"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Range("C4").Value Like "*Yes*" Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The destination sheet is sheet1. I need it to keep pulling every time a new item number is scanned. So it would start at A1, then next item number scanned would go to A2, etc

Comment: What do you mean by "a new item number is scanned"?  Do you mean someone (or something) (or some code) is entering data somewhere?  If so, where?  How do you tell when the "scan" has occurred?  Will a `Worksheet_Change` event fire to enable `Sheet1!A?` to be updated at the appropriate time?

Comment: Data is being entered in A4. That is the only cell that is touched. This data pulls from another sheet and provides either a yes or no response. What i am looking for is a way to list all of those item numbers that provide a yes response

Comment: It sounds like you want a `Worksheet_Change` event on sheet "Sheet7" that checks for a change to cell A4 only and, when it occurs, uses the code in my answer (but replacing `ActiveCell` with the next unused row in `Sheet1!A:A`)